how to set feature and label zIndex independently
I have a map with a polygon layer below a line layer. However I need the polygon labels to be above the line labels, or have a higher priority in decluttering. The only way that I have found to do this is to make the polygon layer a Layer Group with two child layers, one for the feature and a second layer for the labels with a higher zIndex than the line layer.  Is there a better or easier way to accomplish this?

Layer zIndex takes precedence over feature zindex so you must load all your features into one layer.  Then style using a style array where you set different zIndex values for the feature outline and its label.


<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v9.1.0/ol.css">
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v9.1.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <script>

const geojsonObject = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  crs: {
    type: 'name',
    properties: {
      name: 'EPSG:3857',
    },
  },
  features: [
    {
      type: 'Feature',
      geometry: {
        type: 'LineString',
        coordinates: [
          [-2e6, -2e6],
          [2e6, 2e6],
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'Feature',
      geometry: {
        type: 'Polygon',
        coordinates: [
          [
            [-2e6, -1e6],
            [2e6, -1e6],
            [0, 1e6],
            [-2e6, -1e6],
          ],
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};

const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject),
});

const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: function (feature) {
    const type = feature.getGeometry().getType();
    return [
      new ol.style.Style({
        zIndex: type === 'Polygon' ? 1 : 2,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: type === 'Polygon' ? 'blue' : 'red',
          width: 10,
        }),
      }),
      new ol.style.Style({
        zIndex: type === 'Polygon' ? 4 : 3,
        text: new ol.style.Text({
          scale: 5,
          text: type,
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: type === 'Polygon' ? 'blue' : 'red',
          }),
        }),
      }),
    ];
  },
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    }),
    vectorLayer,
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0.25e6],
    zoom: 5,
  }),
});


  </script>
</body>

</html>



